# Is it possible to extract all pairs from a JavaScript object and put them in rows and columns in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to programming and am trying to extract values from an API.

The connection to the API went fine, but I can't extract all pairs (Property:property Value) from a JavaScript object and put them into rows and columns in Google Sheets. Is this possible?

[image: As in the picture: I was able to access the "timeline" information. Can I put the pairs in rows and columns in Google Sheet?]

Example:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-31 | 431.0 |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | 1177.0 |
| 3 | 2022-11-02 | 827.0 |
| 4 | 2022-11-03 | 878.0 |
| 5 | 2022-11-04 | 704.0 |
| 6 | 2022-11-05 | 909.0 |
| 7 | 2022-11-06 | 1135.0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Thank you very much!
Sorry if I made any mistakes, I'm just starting to learn!

Comment: You can use `Object.entries(impressionsPerDay)` to convert the object into an array of `[key, value]` items.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thank you! I did this and I made some progress: 

var impressionsPerDay = results["summary"]["impr."]["timeline"]
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(impressionsPerDay)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }

Now I will try to put this information into the table! Thank you very much!